# Polynomial interpolation and least squares method for approximating the value of a function

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation

Given a table with x and f(x) values, g(x) a non-linear least squares approximation, and p(x) the Lagrange interpolating polynomial that passes through all of the points in the given table. What would be the best approximation on f, for a point x = k by only using p(x) and g(x)?

Intuitively I thought about calculating p(k) and g(k), then taking the middle point of both, however I have no idea if this is reasonable to think of, nor if it is the best approximation for f(k). Is there a visual way to think of this problem? Or will I have to use the properties of both p and g to find the optimal approximation?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).